# Detect Twitter URL PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I'm trying to validate the Twitter URL which my users will submit.

This is what I have:

```
$twitter = "http://twitter.com/jack";
$parse = parse_url($twitter);
if($parse['host'] !== 'www.twitter.com') {
    $error[] = "Invalid Twitter URL.";
}
```

That doesn't seems to do the job. I don't really want to use regular expressions as the `parse_url` seems to be made for this kind of validation.

Anyone knows what's going wrong here?

Comment: `print_r($parse)` is your friend. check what you get back from that

Comment: `Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => twitter.com [path] => /jack )`

Comment: That answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for `www.twitter.com` but the host in the URL is just `twitter.com`, so check for that instead.

Comment: PHP, why do you always have to bug me with the smallest things. Thanks Thief.

Comment: TBH, that problem wasn't realy PHP-related  in the end ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (I haven't test this so tell me if it work):

```
 $twitter = "http://twitter.com/jack";
 $link = str_replace("www.","",$twitter);
 $link = str_replace("https://","",$link);
 $link = str_replace("http://","",$link);
 $host = explode(".",$link);
 echo $host[0]; //Will give you "twitter"
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 1):

If you put $parse into var_dump() function, you get the result:

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(11) "twitter.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/jack"
}
```

So host is not "www.twitter.com" but "twitter.com".